Implementing multicast in Java, but sometimes other hosts fail to receive multicast messages
I'm implementing multicast with Java, but I've encountered some issues. When I start with [Host A receiver -> Host B receiver -> Host A sender], Host B cannot receive the multicast messages. However, when I start with [Host B receiver -> Host A receiver -> Host A sender], Host B can receive the multicast messages. Host A and Host B are in the same LAN. What could be causing this?
Here is my receiver and sender code.
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.MulticastSocket;

/**
 * @author 肖嘉威 xjw580@qq.com
 * @date 2024/4/23 11:33
 */
public class MulticastSender {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("234.2.3.4");
        int port = 12122;
        MulticastSocket ms = null;

        try {
            ms = new MulticastSocket(port);
            ms.joinGroup(group);
            while (true) {
                String message = "Hello " + new java.util.Date();
                byte[] buffer = message.getBytes();
                DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, group, port);
                ms.send(dp);
                System.out.println("发送数据报给" + group + ":" + port);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (ms != null) {
                try {
                    ms.leaveGroup(group);
                    ms.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }

            }
        }
    }
}


import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.MulticastSocket;

/**
 * @author 肖嘉威 xjw580@qq.com
 * @date 2024/4/23 11:34
 */
public class MulticastReceiver {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InetAddress group = InetAddress.getByName("234.2.3.4");
        int port = 12122;
        MulticastSocket ms = null;
        try {
            ms = new MulticastSocket(port);
            ms.joinGroup(group);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            while (true) {
                DatagramPacket dp = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                ms.receive(dp);
                String s = new String(dp.getData(), 0, dp.getLength());
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally
        {
            if (ms !=null)
            {
                try
                {
                    ms.leaveGroup(group);
                    ms.close();
                } catch (IOException e) { }
            }
        }
    }
}


I used wireshark. This is the result of the first boot sequence
Host B

Host A

This is the result of the second boot sequence
Host B

Host A


Can you look at this using a packet sniffer?  Especially close to Host B?  What do you see on the network that looks different?

Looks to me like a networking issue.  If there are no packets at all on B's side, there can't be any way to receive them.  Either a firewall issue on A (those packets are filtered out) or a router or other equipment between the two is filter those packets out.  (I didn't analyze this carefully and I'm not an expert, if you really need help with networking another SE like [networkengineering.se] or [https://superuser.com/] might be a better fit.)

If either of these hosts are connected to the LAN via Wi-Fi, it could be a Wi-Fi problem. Multicast is extra tricky on Wi-Fi, and historically a lot of Wi-Fi products have had buggy multicast implementations. So if you have any Wi-Fi involved, consider switching to wired Ethernet just to see if it was your networking hardware, not your code, that was letting you down.

By the way did you verify that you have bi-directional multicast connectivity between these two hosts before trying your code? If not, consider pinging the all-hosts multicast address (224.0.0.1) from each host, and make sure each host sees the other host respond (but beware of Windows, which I'm told doesn't always respond to multicast or broadcast pings). Anyway, it's a good idea to make sure multicast is working in both directions on your LAN before testing your own multicast code.

@Spiff Yes, my Host A and Host B are both connected via WiFi. When I switch Host B to a wired connection, Host A and Host B can both receive multicast messages.
